# Parameter "f" in GET api/issues/search

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I am trying to use the Web Service API - specifically the parameter `f` for the API `GET api/issues/search`.

The documentation says that I can use this to specify the fields to return.

But I can't get it to work. I keep getting the error response below. Is this parameter not yet supported?  My Sonarqube deployment is version 5.0.1.

> `{"errors":[{"msg":"Value of parameter 'f' (KEY) must be one of: []"}]}`

Here is my request:

```
{
    url: sonarHostUrl + "/api/issues/search",
    type: "GET",
    data:
    {
        assigned: "true",
        componentRoots: projectKey,
        statuses: "OPEN,CONFIRMED,REOPENED",
        ps: "-1",
        hideRules: "true",
        ignorePaging: "true",
        s: "SEVERITY",
        f: "KEY,SEVERITY,ASSIGNEE"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the 'f' parameter is documented but it's in fact not used => It has been fixed in 5.2 : http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6195

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it is evident that f is expected to be an array rather than a string. So you need to put it like this:

```
f: ["KEY","SEVERITY","ASSIGNEE"]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think that is it - its just like the "statuses" parameter - it needs to be a value for the query string parameter "f" - as per documentation - "Comma-separated list of the fields to be returned in response. All the fields are returned by default."